# Factory girl conflict between field names with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

For legacy reasons, I have a model in Rails with two fields: `city` and `city_id`.

`city` is a string with the city name.
`city_id` is a reference to a `city` object.

How should I declare my factory with factory_girl?

I would like to populate both city_id and city like this:

```
   factory :address do
     street "Street X"
     city          #uses city factory
     city "MyCity" #uses legacy city   
   end
```

But this is not possible. How to differentiate between these two city fields?

Comment: why cant get city name from the reference city object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations), you can only use the implicit association when you're following the normal conventions.  So for this case you will need to use an explicit call to the `association` method.

In the example below, replace `:replace_this` with whatever the `belongs_to` association in your model is called:

```
factory :address do
  street "Street X"
  association :replace_this, factory: :city      #uses city factory
  city "MyCity" #uses legacy city   
end
```